# How to show this simple inequality involving $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Let $v_1, v_2$ be in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ with $v_1, v_2 \geq c_0 > 0$.

Define $$a = \frac{c_0 + |v_1-v_2|_{L^\infty}}{c_0}$$. Why is it true that
$$\frac{v_1}{a} \leq v_2?$$

I have been trying for 30 minutes to prove this but I don't see how to deal with the norm term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a\geq 1$ by definition. So if $v_1(x)<v_2(x)$ the inequality is automatically satisfied.

If $v_1(x)\geq v_2(x)$ I get using $\dfrac{v_2}{c_0}\geq 1$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
v_1(x) & = & v_2(x)+v_1(x)-v_2(x) \\
 & \leq & v_2(x)+\dfrac{v_2}{c_0}(v_1(x)-v_2(x)) \\
 & = & v_2(x)+\dfrac{v_2}{c_0}|v_1(x)-v_2(x)| \\
 & \leq & v_2(x)+\dfrac{v_2}{c_0}||v_1-v_2||_{\infty} \\
 & = & av_2(x)
\end{eqnarray*}